# desktop ruby file run a script that connects with a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've use irb and console to write lots of scripts and have switched to writing single .rb files in textmate and then command+r to run it. This is really cool because I can keep all my code in one spot and just hit command+r.

So now I want it to get data from a rails app which of course has a sqlite3 database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to access the database from outside Rails is to use the sqlite3-ruby gem.  [Find documentation here](https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby#readme).

Here is some example code copied from the link above on GitHub:

```
require "sqlite3"

# Open a database
db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"

# Find a few rows
db.execute( "select * from numbers" ) do |row|
  p row
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails includes a console, which is an IRB session pre-wired to load the models and make your DB connection, among other things. It makes it easy to do adhoc what-if's without having to manually require the needed Rails modules and perform the DB connection.

Also, Rails has a "script runner" called, amazingly enough, `rails runner`. It lets you run code within the context of your Rails app, without having to add the routines inside the controller or a model. It's great for utility scripts that shouldn't be part of the main app stack, but still need to access to the models and database. See `rails runner -h` from your Rails' app directory.

SO has [some other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Brails+%2Brunner) about runner that might help.

Comment: looks like rails runner is like with cron and for scheduled tasks.

Comment: Not necessarily for cron jobs, but it works very well that way. If cron can run a task, you can do the same thing from the command-line, since cron is basically doing what you'd type, only at regular intervals.